# .shuffle method in python ends up in an infinite loop unless I remake the list being shuffled

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, shuffle

Here is the code:

```
def share_diagonal(x0, y0, x, y):
dy = abs(x - x0)
dx = abs(y - y0)
return dy == dx


def col_clashes(list_rows_queens, coluna):
    for index in range(coluna):
    if share_diagonal(index, list_rows_queens[index], coluna, list_rows_queens[coluna]):
        return True
return False


def has_clashes(solucao):
    for coluna in range(1, len(solucao)):
        if col_clashes(solucao, coluna):
            return True
    return False


def check_repeat(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                return i
    return False

def test(x):
    print(x)


def main():
    # random handle
    import random
    rng = random.Random()

    # makes a list of solutions
    solution = list(range(8))

    # initializes variables
    numbers_found = 0
    tries = 0

    #makes a list to be appended.
    unique = []


    # main loop code

    while numbers_found < 10:
        rng.shuffle(solution)                                      
        tries += 1                                                 
        if not has_clashes(solution) and solution not in unique:   
            print("Solution {0} found after {1:>} {2:>}".format(solution, tries, "tries"))
            tries = 0                                                                 
            numbers_found += 1
            unique.append(solution)                                                         
            solution = list(range(8))   # THIS LINE MADE THE CODE WORK
    print("Done. Unique solutions: {0}".format(unique))
main()
```

When I didn't have the solution = list(range(8)) in the main while loop, I would end up with an infinite loop and if I tried to get around it, the numbers just wouldn't shuffle (I tried making a function to append the numbers to a list = [] and then re-checking for solutions, all of them ended up either equal or changing between a and, i.e. [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...

Here is the traceback for the infinite loop:

> ```
> /home/****/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python /home/****/PycharmProjects/LearningToThinkLikeAComputerScientist/c14_Exercises/3.py
> Solution [5, 2, 4, 7, 0, 3, 1, 6] found after 436 tries
> ```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/****/PycharmProjects/LearningToThinkLikeAComputerScientist/c14_Exercises/3.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/****/PycharmProjects/LearningToThinkLikeAComputerScientist/c14_Exercises/3.py", line 51, in main
    rng.shuffle(solution)                                      # Shuffles the list solution
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 276, in shuffle
    j = randbelow(i+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 231, in _randbelow
    if type(random) is BuiltinMethod or type(getrandbits) is Method:
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I just would like to understand to further improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glancing through the code, this is a manifestation of one of the most common `gotchas` around mutable objects and name references. [Obligatory Recommended reading here.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)
The issue is that names are just references to the actual underlying python object that they represent. When you append `solution` to the `unique` list via `unique.append(solution)` , `unique[0]` and `solution` both are referring to the same object.

`rng.shuffle(solution)` is shuffling the object referred to by the `solution` variable in-place, thus `solution` and `unique[0]` both reflect the change, because they both still refer to the same object.

A simpler example to demonstrate.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a 
print(b)
a.append(4) #modifying the object referred to by a using one of its methods.
print(b) #[1,2,3,4]
print(a is b) #is keyword can be used to check if they are both the same object
print(id(a)) 
print(id(b)) #both id are same.
```

And you can go on from there.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
b.append(a)
print(b)
a.append(4)
print(b)
import random
rng = random.Random()
rng.shuffle(a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Because of this, after the first time you enter the if block, and `unique.append(solution)`, `solution not in unique` condition always returns returns `False` , thus your loop gets stuck because you aren't entering the `if` block anymore, and so `numbers_found` does not get updated after.

If you ever need to assign a list but ensure you do not run into this issue, make sure you create a fresh copy of the list.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.copy()
print(b is a) #false
print(id(a))
print(id(b))

a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:] #slices to create a copy of the entire list.
print(b is a) #false
```